# Magento2 not getting current time

Tags: magento2, timezone, time

I have tried different options but i am not getting the current time, time shows the gmt time, but actual time setting is asia/kolkatta, any one done this, please update the answer.

```
protected $datetime;

public function __construct(Context $context,
        ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime $datetime
    ) {
        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->storeManager  = $storeManager;
        $this->datetime      = $datetime;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
$current_time   = $this->datetime->gmtDate();// this will return only gmt time
```

Not the time i have set in the admin configuration locale timezone.

Comment: Are you testing it in localhost?

Comment: yes i am using localhost now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    $objDate = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\Timezone');
    $currentTime = $objDate->formatDatetime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
    $currentTimestamp = strtotime($objDate->formatDatetime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s")));//timestamp
```

Answer (score 0):

**Instead of below line:**

```
\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime $datetime
```

**Try to use this : **

```
 \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface::formatDate();
```

(by injecting dependency to construct)

Comment: This script is not working

Answer (score 0):

You can try with format date as below:

```
public function __construct(Context $context,
        ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime \TimezoneInterface $datetime
    ) {

        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->storeManager  = $storeManager;
        $this->datetime      = $datetime;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

$current_time   = $this->datetime->date()->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: i am not getting the value

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, here you need to change 'Asia/Kolkata' as per you need zone.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$date_value = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface');
$today = $date_value->date()->format('m/d/y H:i:s');
$dateTimeAsTimeZone = $date_value->date(new \DateTime($today))->format('m/d/y H:i:s');
```

Hope it works!